# Infinite loop when calculating compound interest

Tags: python, infinite-loop

I'm learning to code in python and I created a code to calculate the amount of a debt its compound interest and the instalments to pay the debt. The code works fine with small amounts but if I go over 10k with the debt the program gets into an infinite loop, can anyone help?

Code below:

```
print('Debt')

a = float(input('Debt amount: $ '))
b = float(input('interest rate: % '))
c = float(input('monthly instalment: R$ '))
b /= 100
x = 0
div = a
ttp = 0

while div > 0:
    inte = div*b
    div = (div + inte) - c
    x += 1

ttp = (c*x) + div
print ('The total of months to pay out the debt was: %d\nThe total paid was: R$%.2f ' % (x, ttp))
print('The total paid in interest was: $ %.2f' % (ttp-a))
```

Comment: Try putting `print(div)` in the loop and see what the values are.

Comment: I think for very high value the rate of inte is higher where as the subtracted C remains constant.

Comment: I've tried print(div) with low amounts it goes perfectly but with an amount over 10k it goes in an eternal loop, if you can run the code you'll see. Try with a=1000, b=1, c = 50. It will calculate it and give the right answer. But if you try a=10000, b=1, c = 500, then will be an eternal loop